# SQL Server CE query error (unhandles exception). Executed from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

```
string query = "Create table " + name + 
               " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), End NVARCHAR(30));";
```

I make of this connection string in C# for a SQL Server CE database (a `.sdf` file). But I am getting an error, as follows:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 77,Token in error = End ]

Executed from the function:

```
public void create_proj_table(string name)
{
    string query = "Create table " + name + " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), End NVARCHAR(30));";

    //open connection
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(query, connection);

        //Execute command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //close connection
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you execute this query?

Comment: Hi, I have added the edit to show how it is executed.

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the edits. I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`END` is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173340%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in Sql.

```
string query = "Create table " + name + " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), End NVARCHAR(30));";
```

If you must use it - i.e., you don't want to change the name of the row - enclose it with '[]', like this:

```
string query = "Create table " + name + " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), [End] NVARCHAR(30));";
```

Answer (score 2):

`End` is a keyword that you cannot use in your own tables - use something like `EndDate` instead.

Also: I would assume `Start` and `End` are dates - I would strongly urge you to use `DATETIME` instad of `NVARCHAR(30)` for storing those!

So I'd change the `CREATE TBALE` statement to something like this:

```
string query =  "CREATE TABLE " + name + 
                " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), Instance INT, StartDate DATETIME, EndDate DATETIME);";
```

and then your code should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The word END is a reserved keyword in SQL CE. If you need to use it you should enclose in square brakets

```
string query = "Create table " + name + " (Manpower_Name NVARCHAR(50), " + 
              "Instance INT, Start NVARCHAR(30), [End] NVARCHAR(30));";
```